# how to create single dll file from 2 or more .cs file?

Tags: c#, dll

I'm new in C#. I'm trying to create a single dll file from multiple .cs source file in visual studio 2012. can anybody help me in this regards?

Comment: Select File -> New Project -> Class library.

Comment: MSDN has a walkthrough for creating a web app with a class library. See it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668164(VS.100).aspx

Comment: _How_ are you currently trying to accomplish that?

Comment: well thank you every one for their valuable suggestions...
finally i did it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a project to your solution with the two files.
Select library type in case the files contain only logic, otherwise make a project depending on the content of the .cs files (but probably it will be some kind of (help) library).

Then in other project(s) use a reference to the project above to be used.